# C# + SQLite [поиск коннектора]

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite

Я разрабатываю в основном приложения для iOS на Objective-C и привык к библиотекам, которые облегчают мне жизнь. Но в скорем времени мне нужно будет написать небольшую программу на C# с использованием базы данных SQLite. Для Objective-C есть замечательный класс, который принимает строку запроса и возвращает данные, вот [пример](http://www.imaladec.com/upload-files/Source/source/SQLiteAccess.zip) коннектора. Может кто-то знает аналогичную библиотеку для C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую эту обертку над System.Data.SQLite: http://krez0n.org.ua/archives/84

Answer (score 0):

Официальный ADO.NET провайдер для SQLite: [`System.Data.SQLite`](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)